# How can I cancel Math-mode, which is inside a function, from the outside?

Tags: math-mode, macros, definition

So the problem is simple. A function takes something and puts it inside math-mode ($$). Can I influence that from the outside?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mathmod#1{$#1$}

\begin{document}
  \mathmod{hello world}
\end{document}
```

prints this: [image]
Is it possible to cancel that mathmode partly from the outside, to make him print something like this: [image] but without moving ***world*** out of the function? Maybe there is any command of fixing condition, after which no other command will affect, or something...

Comment: NB! The question is absolutely theoretical, whether it is possible or not. (no practical solution is needed)

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside `\mathmod` you use `$` to start and end math mode. Inside it, just to the opposite thing: use `$` to start and end text mode (take care of the space!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mathmod#1{$#1$}
\begin{document}
  \mathmod{hello$ world $and$ hello $world\ again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS. You are going to troll most editors with this command ;-) For example, my editor:

[image]

Comment: This reminds me of a sql injection for some reason haha